# Why is it required to add certain fields as a parameter to the constructor in C++

Tags: c++, class, c++-chrono

Probably a simple a question, but I haven't found anything yet. For the code below, the IDE complains about the field and suggests to "Add as parameter to the constructor".

```
#include <chrono>
class TestClass {
private:
    std::chrono::time_point start;
public:
    TestClass(){
        start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    }
};
```

Question 1: What is wrong about the code?

Question 2: How is it possible to define a `time_point` as a field?

Comment: `std::chrono::time_point start{ std::chrono::steady_clock::now() };` to declare the member variable *and* its initializer (if not otherwise provided in a constructor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::chrono::time_point`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point) is a template class, meaning you can not instantiate it without giving the required template parameters. In this case that's the first template parameter `Clock`. I.e. you need to tell for which clock you want to store a time point.

You can fix that by adding your clock:

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> start;
```

But clocks also have a `time_point` type alias, so you write the shorter:

```
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start;
```

Answer (score 3):

Any fields not listed in the constructor's initializer list will be default initialized. So your code is equivalent to this.

```
TestClass() : start() {
  start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
}
```

For things like strings or vectors, this is harmless but silly. We default-construct an empty string or vector and then *assign* another one to it using `operator=`. But `std::chrono::time_point` doesn't have a default constructor, so you can't initialize it this way. Instead, place the argument to the constructor in the initializer list.

```
TestClass() : start(std::chrono::steady_clock::now()) {}
```

You should do this anyway, even if the type can be default constructed. It's more efficient and correct to initialize the value the first time, rather than letting default initialization happen and then assigning to it. But you *must* do this if there's no default constructor.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo "*Any fields not listed in the constructor's initializer list will be default initialized*" - only if they define a default constructor (which `time_point` does), otherwise they are not initialized at all. "*`std::chrono::time_point` doesn't have a default constructor*" - [yes, it does](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/time_point): "*creates a time_point representing the Clock's epoch (i.e., `time_since_epoch()` is zero).*"

Comment: This answer does not solve the problem. Without giving the template parameters as @Chronial suggested it is still wrong.